# In Doraemon what is Big G's (Takeshi Gouda) dialogue style?

Tags: translation, written-language

In some written English translations [Big G](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/Takeshi_Gouda) doesn't *sound* like he has a very standard accent. He can go from sounding almost like a hickish American to dropping British ghetto slang terms. I'm not sure if he is supposed to be cool or rustic.

What is Big G's (Takeshi Gouda) original dialogue style?

Comment: I don't see how this is a question about Japanese.

Answer (score 2):

He talks "normally" in Japanese using "rough" language like ore or -ee endings of verbs, and he often threatens the other children with expressions like ただでは済まねえ or something like that. His speech is a little slurred but he doesn't have a regional accent.